# Cant see Twiitter Feed in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, internet-explorer-8

I have a HTML page where I want to show the twiiter feeds.

I can see the Feeds in the chrome and Firefox. But I am unable to see the feed in the IE 8. Please see the twitter widget i applied.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 tweets">
                    <div style="margin-top: 45px">
                        <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TheIndiaStartup" data-widget-id="558588503546531841">Tweets by @TheIndiaStartup</a>
                        <script>!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may be the reason:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/update-on-twitter-for-websites-ie7-and-ie8-browser-support/28234

> This post is to let you know about our plan to fully drop widgets
>   support for IE7 imminently, and a proposal to drop support for IE8 in
>   January 2015. Please read on for details and caveats.

Comment: You need to check the CSS for the Twitter-feed-script. OR put a link here to the website so we can check.

Comment: which link do you want ? I am working on my localhost

Comment: Have you built your Twitter-feed alone, or have you installed a plugin from somewhere? That might help us help you.

Comment: I have not built any twitter feed on my own, its the twitter widget which twitter provides us. I have taken from their.!

Comment: You can go to the `twitter widget section` You will get an Idea that how it is created.!!

Comment: So you mean to say, twitter widgets does not supports IE8.??

Comment: I marked it answer but I got a point that Twitter has stopped giving support for the IE 8 browser.